# Does Xcode 13.4 and Flutter 3.0 work fine?

Tags: xcode, flutter, build, watchos, flutter-3.0

Previous version (Xcode 13.3 and Flutter 2.10) have some build time errors.

> *xcodebuild[62848:6695836] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
> Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of
> plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
> ** BUILD FAILED ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgraded flutter version to 2.8 and it seems working upto xcode v 13.4.1. Don't know why it doesn't working for higher versions of flutter.

Answer (score 4):

Upgraded to xcode 13.4 and flutter 3.0. Getting the following error.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-05-18 15:24:19.369 xcodebuild[2195:13656] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of
    plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-05-18 15:24:19.369 xcodebuild[2195:13656] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: okay thanks  it seems still issue persist

Comment: Hi did anyone find a solution to this yet. I just updated my flutter version and I started getting the same error message

Comment: I have also that kind of issue. What is the reason and solution of that problem? There is no any logical and useful solution in the internet.

Comment: For the time being I've downgraded to Xcode 13.2.1 to continue my dev

Comment: Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

I double checked the environment.
Reinstalled basic stuff from Terminal plus Xcode and Flutter and nothing.
MacBook Pro M1.. and still stuck.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

latest xcode 13.4.1 and flutter 3.0.5 works fine